# Expected Rolls To Obtain a $6$ Given that $6$ Comes Before $5$

Tags: probability

I posted this question before, but did not obtain any insight on why my specific approach is wrong. Would appreciate any correction.

Roll a fair standard 6−sided die until a 6 appears. Given that the first 6 occurs before the first 5, find the expected number of times the die was rolled.

I approached this by setting up the below sum for the expectation. My logic was that we can choose between 4 values (1-4) for the values before the 6, and then the last value must be a 6, as such the expectation is:

$E = \sum_{x = 1}^{\infty} x*P(X=x) = \frac{1}{6} * (1) + \frac{4}{6}\frac{1}{6} * (2) + (\frac{4}{6})^2\frac{1}{6} * (3)... $

I then solved this equation by obtaining a geometric series by subtracting $E - \frac{4E}{6}$.

Summing the geometric series and solving for E, the answer I get is $\frac{3}{2}$, which is clearly wrong.

The correct answer is $3$. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: I directed you to look at a similar problem.  Did you do that? Your solution makes no sense at all. It just seems random.

Comment: As the link I sent you before points out, restricting the sample space is non trivial. Most careless ways to do that yield bad results.

Comment: Here,  the usual wrong idea would be to say that this was the same as looking at a 5 sided die, with faces $1,2,3,4,6$ and remark that for that die the answer would be $5$. But,  this is not the same problem.

Comment: I did look at the link, but I am not restricting sample space here. I am going through all possible winning combinations: getting a 6 straight away, getting a value (1-4) then a 6, getting 2 rolls (1-4) then a 6, and so on. Why does this logically make no sense?

Comment: Because you are ignoring the probability that you hit one of those good sequences.  Conditional probability requires you to weigh in the probability that you are in the restricted space.

Comment: Here,  since there is a $.5$ chance that $6$ precedes $5$, you could correct by dividing by $.5$ but you reported a different result the [first time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805870/expected-number-of-rolls-to-obtain-6-given-that-no-5s-have-preceded-it)

Comment: The approach suggested by the link is much better.  It shows that the problem is equivalent to asking "what's the expected number of times you can throw a number $≤4$ before you throw something else?"  Since the probability of throwing something else is $\frac 13$, the answer is $3$.

Comment: So in the above sum, if I multiply every term by 2, that should accurately reflect it. So for example, for the first term (probability of stopping on the first roll), it should be $\frac{2}{6}$ instead of $\frac{1}{6}$ to reflect that a 5 is basically a 6, as it is given that 6 occurs before 5?

Comment: Conditional probability should divide by the probability that you are in the restricted space.  In this case, that probability is just $.5$

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: FYI - unless you are complaining about nobody getting mad, it should have been "insight", not "incite".

Answer (score 0):

You have to have $\sum P(X=k)= 1$ if you want to apply expected value formula. In your answer
$$
\sum P(X=k)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{4}{6^2}\dots = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
This 1/2 corresponds to the probability of having 6 before 5 in any series of rolls. The question is saying "Given that 6 comes before 5", meaning you have to calculate the probability among the series of rolls in which 6 comes before 5.  That is, you have to calculate the conditional probability for each case. Let us calculate the conditional probability:
$$
P(\text{having $6$ at $k$-th roll}| 6\text{ comes before }5)=
\frac{P(k-\text{th roll is $6$ and $6$ comes before }5)}{P(6\text{ comes before }5)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{6} \cdot \left(\dfrac{4}{6}\right)^{k-1}}{ \dfrac{1}{2}}
$$

It means you have to divide all of your probabilities with 1/2, so you will get the expected value as 3 eventually.

I verified these by doing an experiment. I ran a program that plays the game 10000000 times. I deleted the games having 5 before 6 and in the remaining games I checked the ratio of the games that ended kth roll to the total number of the remaining games (undeleted ones.)

Comment: Thanks Daniele. It looks much better now.